# TouchesBeganWithEvent not getting called in SKScene

Tags: cocoa, sprite-kit, xamarin.ios, skscene, xamarin.mac

I have an issue with touch events in SKScene, those are not getting called when i touch sprites in scene :(

Here is my code

```
public class FallingObjectsScene : SKScene
{
    public override void DidMoveToView(SKView view)
    {
        base.DidMoveToView(_view);

        UserInteractionEnabled = true;

        Image = new SKSpriteNode();
        Image.Position = new CGPoint(labelXpostion, skView.Bounds.GetMaxY());
        Image.Texture = imageTexture.Texture;
        Image.Size = new CGSize(60, 60);
        Image.Speed = 3.01f;
        Image.AnchorPoint = new CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5);
        AddChild(Image);
    }
 }

 public override void TouchesBeganWithEvent(NSEvent theEvent)
 {
    base.TouchesBeganWithEvent(theEvent);

    var point = theEvent.LocationInNode(this);
    var touchNode = GetNodeAtPoint(point);
    try
    {
        //... some code
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        LoggingManager.Error(exception);
        ClearScreenTouches();
    } 
 }
```

can anyone help to resolve this,
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your grammar looks weird, on Xcode 8.2.1 & Swift 3, it should looks like:

```
class MenuScene: SKScene {

    override init(){...}

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
       ...
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in (touches ){
            let location = touch.location(in: self)
            let touchNode = atPoint(location)

            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response , I followed same code above and i am using Xamarin Technology, Technology doesn't matter but that method not being called.

Comment: From the code you posted, it looks as though your touchesBegan function in not with your class definition, which is what Chen was getting at,

Comment: @SteveIves Yes but touchesBegan function not showing in my Xamarin Technology :( that's why i am using mouse events.